# "extends ParentClass" won't inherit ParentClass attributes with @MappedSuperClass

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Auction {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String title;
    @Column
    private String description;
    @Column
    private String category;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private long sellerId;
    @Column
    private String urlPicture;

}

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "inverseauction")

public class InverseAuction extends Auction{

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int startingPrice;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss[.SSS][.SS][.S]")
    private LocalDateTime expiryDate;
}
```

The only attributes my `@GetMapping` returns are `startingPrice` and `expiryDate` , for some reason the Auction attributes are invisible to Auction.

My only guess is to add some SpringBoot Annotation but I don't know which one, I tried some but won't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add getters/setters to your MappedSuperClass and may have to create a custom AllArgsConstructor as Lombok doesn't do a super() in its generated AllArgsConstructor.

Answer (score 1):

`private long id` and everything else in `Auction` is only visible to the Auction class because of the private keyword.

If you want them to be visible to subclasses, such as `InverseAuction` you can use protected instead of private.

Or, if you want to follow the Lombok route, you can add `@Getter(value = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)` to the Auction class.